# Why PHP change plus icon to space

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When i tried to input "iPhone 8+" on product name, it'll return "iPhone 8 " (with space).

I have tried using urlencode() on my php and it'll return "iPhone+8+"

How to make it to return "iPhone 8+"

This is my javascript with jquery code

```
  $("#submit-btn").click(function(){
      //get all value
      var product_name = $("#product_name").val();
      var stock = $("#product_stock").val();
      var price = $("#product_price").val();
      var product_desc = $("#product_desc").val();
      var product_img = $('#img-select').val().split('\\').pop();

      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "add.php",
       data: `product_name=${product_name}&product_stock=${stock}&product_price=${price}&product_desc=${product_desc}&img=${product_img}`,
        success: function(data) {
          location.reload();
        }
      });      
  });
```

This is my php code

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';

$nama = urlencode($_POST["product_name"]);
$stock = $_POST["product_stock"];
$price = $_POST["product_price"];
$desc = $_POST["product_desc"];
$img = $_POST["img"];

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO product_list(id,product_name,stock,price,product_desc,sold,img) VALUES('','$nama','$stock','$price','$desc','','$img')");

?>
```

Comment: You haven't url encoded the product_name, on server side you're decoding it. `var product_name = encodeURIComponent( $("#product_name").val() );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `encodeURIComponent` to encode that string:

```
data: `product_name=${encodeURIComponent(product_name)}&product_stock=${encodeURIComponent(stock)}&product_price=${encodeURIComponent(price)}&product_desc=${encodeURIComponent(product_desc)}&img=${encodeURIComponent(product_img)}`,
```

infact `encodeURIComponent('IPhone 8+')` outputs `IPhone%208%2B` and so it has encoded the `+`, and so is no more recognized as  by your server
Or even better, use `POST` method

Comment: Or even better, just serialize the form and send it. LE: since you use jQuery `data: $('form').serialize()`

Comment: @MujnoiGyulaTamas in one of the fields is not serializing it normally

Comment: @Berto99 Usually data sanitization happens in the backend, Could have used FormData as well, object to append too etc. Seems to me that his sending the image name to the backend. LE: as you can see in his php code his not doing any backend sanitization, which is bad.

Comment: @MujnoiGyulaTamas there is a lot of bad practice in this code, starting from the fact that is encoding post data as he would have done for a get request, however it is not what he asked for, i've focus the answer about how to solve his problem, and why it is happening